# How do I fix the following issue: Could not write JSON: Failed making field 'java.lang.ThreadLocal#threadLocalHashCode' accessible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson, crud, thread-local

I am trying to build the Create section of a CRUD Watchlist API in spring boot for an assignment. I need to store my data in a json file instead of a database, to serialize and deserialize I'm using gson when adding new data to my watchlist.

The problem being when I send a post request to the API I get the following error:

**IDE Returns this:**

```
2023-11-12T12:13:11.613Z  WARN 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Failed making field 'java.lang.ThreadLocal#threadLocalHashCode' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.]
```

I'm expecting that when I send my post request the data writes to a gson file and it appends new entries to the end of existing watchlist

Here is the section of my code that write to gson:

```
@Service
public class WriteToJson {

    private CreateWatchlist createList;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WriteToJson.class);

    @Autowired
    public WriteToJson(CreateWatchlist createList) {
        this.createList = createList;
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new DateTypeAdapter()).create();

    String jsonString = gson.toJson(createList);

    public void writeToJson() throws FailureToIOJsonException {
        String jsonRepo = "JsonWatchlist.json";
        try {
           
            List<Watchlist> existingListData = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Watchlist>>() {}.getType());

            if(existingListData == null) {
                existingListData = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            existingListData.add(createList);

            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(jsonRepo, true)) {
                gson.toJson(existingListData, writer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Serialized watchlist failed to write to Json file.", e);
                throw new FailureToIOJsonException("IOException occurred while attempting to write new data to JSON.", e);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Failed to add createWatchlist to the new entry array", e);
            throw new FailureToIOJsonException("Exception occurred while trying to write createWatchlist to the addEntry array.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the input of the constructor for the data to be serialized:

```
@Component
public class CreateWatchlist extends Watchlist{

    private UUID uuid;
    private String stockName;
    private String symbol;
    private boolean owned;
    private String status;
    private String currency;
    private LocalDate datePurchased;
    private Integer unitsOwned;
    private double profit;
    private double pointsChange;
    private double open;
    private double close;
    private double intradayHigh;

    public CreateWatchlist() {
    super();
    }

        public CreateWatchlist(UUID uuid, String stockName, String symbol, boolean owned, String status, String currency,
            LocalDate datePurchased, Integer unitsOwned, double profit, double pointsChange, double open, double close,
            double intradayHigh) {
        super();
            
        if(uuid == null){
            this.uuid = generateUUID("default");
        }else{
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.owned = owned;
        this.status = status;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.datePurchased = datePurchased;
        this.unitsOwned = unitsOwned;
        this.profit = profit;
        this.pointsChange = pointsChange;
        this.open = open;
        this.close = close;
        this.intradayHigh = intradayHigh;
    }

    //  public CreateWatchlist() {
    // }

        public UUID generateUUID(String stockName){
        int stockNameCount = getStocknameincrement().getOrDefault(stockName, 0);
        getStocknameincrement().put(stockName, stockNameCount + 1);
        return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes((stockName + stockNameCount).getBytes());
    }

       public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    } 

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }
    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public boolean isOwned() {
        return owned;
    }

    public void setOwned(boolean owned) {
        this.owned = owned;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public LocalDate getDatePurchased() {
        return datePurchased;
    }

    public void setDatePurchased(LocalDate datePurchased) {
        this.datePurchased = datePurchased;
    }

    public Integer getUnitsOwned() {
        return unitsOwned;
    }

    public void setUnitsOwned(Integer unitsOwned) {
        this.unitsOwned = unitsOwned;
    }

    public double getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }

    public void setProfit(double profit) {
        this.profit = profit;
    }

    public double getPointsChange() {
        return pointsChange;
    }

    public void setPointsChange(double pointsChange) {
        this.pointsChange = getClose() - getOpen();
    }

    public double getOpen() {
        return open;
    }

    public void setOpen(double open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

    public double getClose() {
        return close;
    }

    public void setClose(double close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public double getIntradayHigh() {
        return intradayHigh;
    }

    public void setIntradayHigh(double intradayHigh) {
        this.intradayHigh = intradayHigh;
    }

        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WatchlistInherited [uuid=" + uuid + ", stockName=" + stockName + ", symbol=" + symbol + ", owned=" + owned + ", status=" + status + ", currency="
        + currency + ", datePurchased=" + datePurchased + ", unitsOwned=" + unitsOwned + ", profit=" + profit
        + ", pointsChange=" + pointsChange + ", open=" + open + ", close=" + close + ", intradayHigh="
        + intradayHigh + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is the error it returns when I make a POST request:

**Postman returns this:**

```
{
    "timestamp": "Nov 12, 2023, 12:13:11 PM",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Failed making field 'java.lang.ThreadLocal#threadLocalHashCode' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.java:128)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.lang.ThreadLocal#threadLocalHashCode' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:294)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:294)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:834)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:812)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:783)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(GsonHttpMessageConverter.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.java:125)\r\n\t... 48 more\r\nCaused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.lang.ThreadLocal.threadLocalHashCode accessible: module java.base does not \"opens java.lang\" to unnamed module @5c0e7ef1\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)\r\n\tat com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35)\r\n\t... 64 more\r\n",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: Failed making field 'java.lang.ThreadLocal#threadLocalHashCode' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.",
    "path": "/watchlist/addEntry"
}
```

I'm unable to find a fix for this issue, and would be very grateful for any assistance.

Here is the code from watchlist below. When I send a POST request in postman I get the two messages shown above, I will go back and highlight them.

```
    public class Watchlist {

//     @JsonProperty
    private static final Map<String, Integer> stockNameIncrement = new HashMap<>();

    public static Map<String, Integer> getStockNameIncrement() {
        return stockNameIncrement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code of your `Watchlist` class as well; most likely it has a field of type `ThreadLocal`. And please also include the stack trace of the exception, or at least parts of it. I am also not sure if your logic for writing to a `FileWriter(..., append=true)` really works as desired, because this will just append another top-level JSON value instead of adding new elements to the existing JSON array in that file.

Comment: Based on the stack trace in the Postman response it looks like this might not actually be related to your `WriteToJson` class (it does not appear anywhere in the stack trace). Could you please include the code of your Spring controller class which defines the REST API? It looks like that might implicitly use Gson for serialization of an object with `ThreadLocal` value.